# How do I record time to results in ImageJ from MicroManager

Tags: imagej

I don't really know the first thing about programming. I am trying to record the intensity of Fluo-4 (fluochrome) over time from regularly stimulated cardiomyocytes as a yz plot.

Furthermore, I am using MicroManager, which is built on ImageJ and can be scripted to in BeanScript, which resembles java. After a lot of trial and error, I have the following script:

```
import ij.*;

numberOfImages = 25;

//the image window must be already open in the GUI (press "Snap Image" at least once) before running this script

IJ.run("Set Measurements...", "integrated redirect=None decimal=3");

for (int i=0; i < numberOfImages; i++)
{
images = mm.live().snap(true);
img = images.get(0);
IJ.run("Measure");
IJ.timeStamp = getTime();  
IJ.setResult("Time", i, timeStamp);
Thread.sleep(10);
}
```

My problem is that the two lines to record the time works in ImageJ (if you remove the "IJ." part) but not in BeanScript through MicroManager.

Without those two lines, the script works, except the duration of each for loop varies by some milliseconds, which is what I am trying to account for by recording the time. How do I solve this?

In the script manager window of MicroManager, I get the following error message.

> Line 14: evaluation error : Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import ij.*;  numberOfImages = 25;  //the image window must be already open in t . . . '' : Field access: bsh.ReflectError: No such field: timeStamp